# RegEx start and finish with letter, allow commas and dashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this regex:

`/^[\a-zøåæäöüß][\a-z0-9øåæäöüß]*(?:\-?[\a-z0-9øåæäöüß,]+)*$/i`

It works fine for a crazy input like `"K61-283øÅ,æk-ken,a-sd"`, but it fails on the cases `"word,"` (so, when there's just one comma).

Also - how can I restrict it that it should start with a letter *after every comma or dash* (so basically - every word)?

*The rule is:* start with a letter and end with alphanumeric; allow alphanumeric, dashes and commas; after each dash or comma there should be a letter

Comment: Are you sure you do not allow `_`? And what does `\w` do? What are your pattern requirements?

Comment: Oh, I see... I thought `\w` allows only alphanumeric...

Comment: Ok, try [`/^[a-zøåæäöüß][a-z0-9øåæäöüß]*(?:[-,][a-z0-9øåæäöüß]+)*$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/RQhsOy/1). Note I removed `?` from after `[-,]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it fails for input `"asd,1dsa"`

Comment: be aware because `\w` does not match your signs `øåæäöüß`

Comment: @Paweł: That is why they are added to the character class.

Comment: i'm working at my regex testing app now https://devrafalko.github.io/regex-tutorial/ you can test there your regex and string input, just replace the regex and text with your ones

Comment: Actually, you still have not precised if there must be  a letter after each `-`, too. If yes, my regex is the answer, else, melpomene's approach is ok to use.

Comment: Sorry that I was unclear. I've edited the OP.

Comment: Ok, use `/^[a-zøåæäöüß][a-z0-9øåæäöüß]*(?:[-,][a-zøåæäöüß][a-z0-9øåæäöüß]*)*$/i`, see https://regex101.com/r/RQhsOy/3.

Comment: @Milkncookiez: Please double check *start and end with a letter* requirement: did you really mean `a0` is invalid? Or - if it is valid - shouldn't it sound as *start and end with an alphanumeric*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[a-zøåæäöüß][a-z0-9øåæäöüß]*(?:[-,][a-zøåæäöüß][a-z0-9øåæäöüß]*)*$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RQhsOy/3)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zøåæäöüß]` - a letter from the defined set
- `[a-z0-9øåæäöüß]*` - 0+ digits or letters from the defined set
- `(?:[-,][a-zøåæäöüß][a-z0-9øåæäöüß]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `[-,]` - a `-` or `,`
  - `[a-zøåæäöüß]` - a letter from the defined set
  - `[a-z0-9øåæäöüß]*` - 0+ digits or letters from the defined set
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This allows `a0` (which is invalid) but doesn't allow `a` (which is valid).

Comment: @melpomene: Why is `a0` invalid? BTW, `a` [is matched](https://regex101.com/r/RQhsOy/4).

Comment: `a0` is ruled out by "*start and end with a letter*" (it ends with a digit). `a` is valid because it's a string that starts and ends with a letter.

Comment: @melpomene: I see what you mean. Honestly, I understood this requirement as "should end with alphanumeric".

Comment: @melpomene: I asked OP in a comment below the question.

Comment: @melpomene, WiktorStribiżew, sorry guys, I got a bit confused. I updated the post with *start with letter and end in alphanumeric*.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly how I "felt" the wording :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2:**

There are two ways to look at your requirements.

1. The top-down view

   We treat the input as a list of one or more words, separated by comma or dash:

   ```
   INPUT = WORD (?: [,\-] WORD )*
   ```

   Each word consists of a letter, followed by zero or more letters or digits:

   ```
   WORD = LETTER [ LETTER DIGIT ]*
   ```

   Translated into JavaScript regex syntax this gives us:

   ```
   WORD = [a-zøåæäöüß][a-zøåæäöüß\d]*
   ```

   And for the whole input (with anchors):

   ```
   /^[a-zøåæäöüß][a-zøåæäöüß\d]*(?:[,\-][a-zøåæäöüß][a-zøåæäöüß\d]*)*$/i
   ```

   (This is Wiktor Stribiżew's answer.)
2. The bottom-up view

   We start by looking at the allowed characters. We know that the first character has to be a letter. After that, there can be zero or more input elements:

   ```
   INPUT = LETTER ELEMENT*
   ```

   Each element is either

   - a letter or digit, or
   - a comma or dash, followed by a letter:

   ```
   ELEMENT = [ LETTER DIGIT ] | [ COMMA DASH ] LETTER
   ```

   Translating this into JavaScript gives us:

   ```
   /^[a-zøåæäöüß](?:[a-zøåæäöüß\d]|[,\-][a-zøåæäöüß])*$/i
   ```

These two regexes are equivalent. The bottom-up regex is shorter and contains less repetitive code. On the other hand, the top-down regex may run faster on some regex engines if the input strings are mostly alphanumeric, with relatively few dashes/commas. On the gripping hand, if your inputs are short, you probably don't care about minuscule performance differences.

---

<strike>Here's a direct encoding of your (revised) requirements:</strike>

```
/^[a-zøåæäöüß](?:(?:[a-zøåæäöüß\d]|[,\-][a-zøåæäöüß])*[,\-]?[a-zøåæäöüß])?$/i
```

The idea is to match a letter, followed by either

- the end of the string (this handles input strings of length 1), or
- a list of 0 or more intermediates, optionally followed by a comma or dash, followed by another letter

Each intermediate is either

- a letter, or
- a digit, or
- a comma or a dash followed by a letter

Comment: Except it fails at `"asd,-asd"`.

Comment: @Milkncookiez I've completely rewritten my answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did another rewrite. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this out: (allows letters and digits after comma or dash)

```
/^[a-zøåæäöüß]([a-z0-9øåæäöüß]|(,|-)[a-z0-9øåæäöüß])*[a-zøåæäöüß]$/i
```

or this: (allows letters after comma or dash)

```
/^[a-zøåæäöüß]([a-z0-9øåæäöüß]|(,|-)[a-zøåæäöüß])*[a-zøåæäöüß]$/i
```

Comment: You don't have to escape `,` or `-`. Your regexes don't allow `a` (which is valid), but they allow `a,0a` (which is invalid).

Comment: `a,a` is another valid input not matched by your regexes.